# .net core 3.0 and Angular 8 - role based authentication (simply way)

Tags: angular, jwt, authorization, .net-core-3.0

I created a web application in .net core 3 and Angular 8 with individual user accounts. I do not know
how to add role information to the token
and how to check it on the angular side. I only have information about the user ID in the token. I've seen examples with JWT, but I think if I have a token with a user ID, I don't need so many changes (just need to add the role information to the token and read it on the angular side).
Also in .net 3.0 login controller after scaffolding lookms diffrent than in examples.
Is there a simply way to update this template ? Or I realy need so many changes?

example i tried: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login